# How to add alert class in viewbag from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here i am trying to add bootstrap alert class to the exception shown in ViewBag.message from controller on clicking the create button. But adding the class shows the exception 'string' does not contain a definition for 'cssClass'.
Below Is Create.cshtml

```
    @model WebApplication8.Models.Info

   @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }
   <h2>Create</h2>

     <div class="errormsg">  
         @ViewBag.message
    </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

     <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Info</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.des, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.des, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.des, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

 <div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </div>

 @section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }
```

Below is Create Action Method In controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,name,des")] Info info)
    {

        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.create(info);                  
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            ViewBag.message =  ex.Message;
            ViewBag.message.cssClass = "alert alert-danger";
            return View(info);
        }
        return View(info);

    }
```

below is Interface Implementer class

```
public class StudentInfo : IStudentInfo
{
    private AbcdEntities db1 = new AbcdEntities();

    public void create(Info info)
    {
        if (info.name!=null)
        {
            if (info.des!=null)
            {
                db1.Infoes.Add(info);
                db1.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {

                throw new Exception("Des Cannot Be Empty");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Name Cannot Be Empty");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your class need to be added to the element that is displaying the message - ie. `<div class="errormsg alert alert-danger">` (and delete the `ViewBag.message.cssClass = "alert alert-danger";` line of code)

Answer (score 0):

`ViewBag.message =  ex.Message;`

You assign to the ViewBag a property *message* passing to it the Exception.Message, a simple string.

`ViewBag.message.cssClass = "alert alert-danger";`

Then you try to access a non existent property of a string.

I think you need to understand better the usage of the *viewBag*, of *dynamics*, and in wich way MVC propose his way to work on *views* with Razor.

If you want a complex object in the viewBag you need to create something similar with a dynamic:

```
ViewBag.Message = new { Text= ex.Message, CssClass = "alert alert-danger" }
```

and then use it in this way:

```
<div class="errormsg @ViewBag.Message.CssClass">  
   @ViewBag.Message.Text
</div>
```

If it is a recurrent way to represent a return message in a view, you can create a viewModel class to represent the message and create an *helper* in Razor to enclosure this render rules in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following to do what you're looking for using Tempdata.

```
@*Display any messages returned from other views*@
<div>
    @*Error Message*@
    @if (TempData["error"] != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger">@TempData["error"]</div>
    }
</div>
```

You will need to check your Viewbag.message for null